# listName of lightning listView

Tags: list-view, lightning-components, lightninglistview

How can we get the value of listName to use lightning listView?
Should I check Salesforce setting?

I wanna use listView for custom object,
but I'm troubled with how to set listName.

```
<lightning:listView aura:id="listViewAccounts"
                            objectApiName="customObject__c"
                            listName="customObject__c_All"
                            rows="10"
                            showSearchBar="true"
                            showActionBar="false"
                            enableInlineEdit="true"
                            showRowLevelActions="false"
                            />
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this SOQL query to get all list names for a custom object.

```
SELECT DeveloperName FROM ListView WHERE SObjectType='customObject__c'
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: Thank you.
It worked well.